# Consuming ArcGIS WMTS service in C#

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, wmts, unity3d

I am looking for a way to use ArcGIS WMTS map service in C# (Actually it is a unity platform and most probably it be used on unity webgl). But I didn't find it yet. There are [JavaScript API avilable](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/), is there any practical way available to use it with C#? with some free available WTMS services.

Comment: I can't answer how to use it without more details, but the WMTS service is just a REST API. So look for the WMTS REST documentation. Then in C# you can make the REST calls using HttpClient class.

Comment: How to read and understand xml file